# How can I display horizontal and vertical dividers between items in the LazyVerticalGrid?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How can I display vertical and horizontal dividers between items in the `LazyVerticalGrid`?

For `LazyColumn` it is possible to do it this way:

```
LazyColumn(...) {
    items(items) { item ->
        Row(item)
        Divider()
    }
}
```

and it will also work for `LazyVerticalGrid` but I'm unsure how to display vertical dividers between items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a 2 different `Divider`s in each cell.

Something like:

```
val numbers = (0..20).toList()

LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Fixed(4)){
    itemsIndexed(numbers) { index, item ->

        Row(Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {

            Column(Modifier.weight(1f),horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                Text(text = "Number")
                Text(text = "  $item",)
                Divider() //Horizontal divider 
            }
            
            //Vertical divider avoiding the last cell in each row
            if ((index+1)%4 != 0) {
                Column() {
                    Divider(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .width(1.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]